# Hook into other module's field formatter?

Tags: entities

Am currently trying to implement a node referenced image field on my Drupal 7 site that will change it's 'view mode' depending on programmatical logic just before render. The field is currently being rendered on a number of content types via their display mode settings, each of which are using the field formatter 'Rendered node'.

#### **first attempt**

My first idea was to implement the following, considering a hook is a hook is a hook:

```
function HOOK_field_formatter_view( $entity_type, $entity, $field ... ){
  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'node_reference_node':
      /* Programatical logic here to modfy field render settings */
    break;
  }
}
```

*Obviously exchanging HOOK for my module's name.*

It didn't really matter if the above would fire before or after the original function `node_reference_field_formatter_view` in `node_reference.module` because I would either override it's output entirely or, hopefully, modify its values before rendering. The only problem is, the above hook seems to function only on a per module basis — i.e. it's not site-wide, so basically it doesn't fire for my module.

Now obviously I can write my own field formatter to output a rendered node. But it seems a bit of a waste considering there is already one that exists.

#### **other approaches**

My other approaches have been to `HOOK_preprocess_node` and `HOOK_preprocess_field` but the former doesn't contain any `view_mode` information, and the latter contains at least 5 different complicated structures that all have references to a `view_mode` property at different levels — and it feels rather hacky to have to modify each of their values. Even when I've changed certain `view_mode` properties the resulting image doesn't change.

#### **question**

Does anyone know of a clean way to step in before a field formatter renders (of a contrib module) and change it's settings on a per page request basis — i.e. by not having to change the actual content type's permanent view mode settings?

Comment: I've been looking for a `hook_field_formatter_view_alter()` or similar for probably over a year now, it just doesn't exist unfortunately. FYI `hook_preprocess_node()` definitely _does_ have `view_mode` available to it, it's in `$vars['view_mode']`, not `$vars['node']->view_mode` which you might have been tempted to try.

Comment: @Clive thanks for the info, oh and for pointing out the `view_mode` on `hook_preprocess_node`, foolish me! I wonder if anything like `hook_field_formatter_view_alter()` this exists in D8...

Comment: I haven't seen anything yet...but then everything's being converted to plugins in D8 (I'm not sure about fields) so it might be that you can just override an existing class to get the job done, that would be ideal. Here's hoping!

Comment: @Clive, have you found your magic alter hook mentioned here for D7?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question mentions that `hook_field_formatter_view()` is only called on the originating module, but you can take ownership of the field formatter via `hook_field_formatter_info_alter()`.

You should be able to set the `module` key of the formatter to MYMODULE like:

```
function MYMODULE_field_formatter_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['some_field_formatter']['module'] = 'MYMODULE';
}
```

**Then** you can implement `MYMODULE_field_formatter_view()`, optionally feeding through the existing module which handled it to get an element to alter.

```
function MYMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  // Your custom logic
  $element = OTHER_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display);
  // Any alterations
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Provide some code?

Comment: Nice solution, I almost never think to take complete possession of another module's business (and relay back after changes)... just tried it out though and I end up with much simpler code. Cheers!

Comment: @ScottJoudry ~ might just be worth noting that if you take over in this way you need to make sure you have methods for all the `field_formatter` functionality of node_reference i.e. `MYMODULE_field_formatter_settings_summary` and `MYMODULE_field_formatter_settings_form` (even if they are just proxy functions back to the original module) otherwise the back-end UI breaks on any display mode panels, when it tried to find these methods in the wrong module.

Comment: The approach of Graham C is interesting, but requires too many overrides.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I realised why my changes to `#view_mode` in either `hook_preprocess_node` and `hook_preprocess_fields` weren't working. *(Thanks to Clive for pointing out that I had totally missed the presence of `#view_mode` in `hook_preprocess_node`)*.

My problem stemmed from the fact that `#view_mode` had already been processed and converted to the correct `#image_style` property — something which I had neglected to search for.

Even so, changing this value seems too heavily dependent on which hook you modified it in. I finally got some code working though, that actually changes the rendered image:

```
function HOOK_preprocess_field( &$vars ){
  $element     = &$vars['element'];
  $entity_type = !empty($element['#entity_type']) ? $element['#entity_type'] : 'unknown';
  $bundle      = !empty($element['#bundle'])      ? $element['#bundle']      : 'unknown';
  $view_mode   = !empty($element['#view_mode'])   ? $element['#view_mode']   : 'unknown';
  $field_name  = !empty($element['#field_name'])  ? $element['#field_name']  : 'unknown';
  switch ( "$entity_type:$view_mode:$bundle/$field_name" ) {
    case 'node:full:mlandingpage/field_lead_image':
      if ( !empty($vars['items']) && 
           ($subelement = &$vars['items'][0]) ) {
        if ( !empty($subelement['field_image']) && 
             ($subfield = &$subelement['field_image'][0]) ) {
          /// this needs to be set to the image_style value, not the view_mode value.
          $subfield['#image_style'] = 'grid-normal-4-cols';
        }
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

The above still doesn't feel very eloquent, but at least it works. I'll take Clive's word on the fact that such an _alter method doesn't exist for field formatters — it's a shame, formatters are an extremely powerful feature of D7, it would be nice to have more augmenting ability.

Anyway, if any future people have any better ideas, answer away :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach will be using the [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer).

If don't use Panelizer but default Drupal view modes or Display Suite, try [hook_field_display_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7) or [hook_field_display_ENTITY_TYPE_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_ENTITY_TYPE_alter/7).

You have entity, display context as well as all the formatter settings there. And you can easily change field render settings.
You can even change field formatter to a different one.

The approach works perfect for me. The only disadvantage is that you might be confused with different settings in the the "Manage display" UI.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/node/2130757
It gives a good example.
hook_field_formatter_third_party_settings_form() is useful to alter the form of the existing field formatter.

But this doesn't work with field groups.